# Problem booting into my system: cryptsetup: lvm is not available

Tags: encryption, luks, cryptsetup

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with full disk encryption using [this](http://thesimplecomputer.info/full-disk-encryption-with-ubuntu) guide. Normally I have to enter one passphrase to unlock `root` and then another one to unlock `swap`, and then the system boots with no issues (`home` gets unlocked automatically). But today, after successfully unlocking `root`, I got the passphrase for `swap` wrong a couple of times and then got the following message: `cryptsetup: lvm is not available`. I tried shutting down the system several times to enter both passphrases again, but after one attempt I got again the same message. This happened to me some time ago, and the only solution I could find was to reinstall the system again.

So my question is: What could have happened to my system and how can I fix it without reinstalling the system again?

I am absolutely sure I know the correct passphrases, so I think this is not the issue.

If it is helpfull, I have a backup of my partitions' LUKS headers (as suggested in the guide) in a safe place. Will restoring the LUKS headers solve my problem?

Also, please take into account that I am a very basic user and can only reliably follow step-by-step guides.

Comment: Carl, did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem now. I suspect it's a corrupted swap partition that just needs to be deleted by booting from a live disk and running gparted to delete it. I suspect using a swap *file* on the encrypted partition would be a better idea and prevent this problem. See "How do I add a swap file?" here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/373206/114401.

Comment: Also, your link to the guide you followed is dead.